# Postgresql 15 - Trailing junk after numeric literal error

Tags: database, postgresql, uuid, numeric, query-error

After the Postgresql update v15, I realised that even I have a column that accepts UUID data type, it will throw me similar error like this whenever I try to Insert UUID data into the table.

Script:

```sql
INSERT INTO public.testing(uuid, rating) VALUES (${uuid}, ${rating});
```

Error:

> error running query error: trailing junk after numeric literal at or near "45c"

Postgresql 15 release note:

> Prevent numeric literals from having non-numeric trailing characters (Peter Eisentraut)

Is there any solution for this issue? Or there an alternative data type that allows storing UUID into my table?

Comment: Ar you sure this is about the UUID? Could you give us an example including the payload for the values?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that you forgot the single quotes around the UUID, so that the PostgreSQL parser took the value for a subtraction and complained that there were letters mixed in with the digits. This may throw a different error on older PostgreSQL versions, but it won't do the right thing either.

Be careful about SQL injection when you quote the values.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> ERROR:  trailing junk after numeric literal at or near "1s"

When I ran the SQL with the identifiers `1st_num` and `2nd_num` as shown below:

```sql
SELECT 2 AS 1st_num, 3 AS 2nd_num;
```

So, I set `_` just before `1st_num` and `2nd_num`, then the error was solved as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT 2 AS _1st_num, 3 AS _2nd_num;
 _1st_num | _2nd_num
----------+----------
        2 |        3
(1 row)
```

[The doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) says below:

> SQL identifiers and key words must begin with a letter (a-z, but also letters with diacritical marks and non-Latin letters) or an underscore (_). Subsequent characters in an identifier or key word can be letters, underscores, digits (0-9), or dollar signs ($). Note that dollar signs are not allowed in identifiers according to the letter of the SQL standard, so their use might render applications less portable. The SQL standard will not define a key word that contains digits or starts or ends with an underscore, so identifiers of this form are safe against possible conflict with future extensions of the standard.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem while fetching data from Postgresql.

> SELECT * FROM table_name  WHERE my_conditions  OFFSET **0FETCH**
> FIRST 1 ROW ONLY

**Reason was the query syntax error.**

I just corrected it as

> SELECT * FROM table_name  WHERE my_conditions  OFFSET **0 FETCH**
> FIRST 1 ROW ONLY

And its working fine.